# how can I print a value that correspond to a different value in two different lists? (python)

Tags: python, list

So I want my program to print from two different lists that correspond to each other. So if one list has ["pen", "paper", "calculator"] and a second list has the prices ["5", "10", "15"] how do I have the program print an object when the user gives a price value. here is the code I'm working with right now:

```
schoollist=["pen", "paper", "calculator"]
pricelist=[5, 10, 15]
userlist =[]
studentprice=int(input("enter your budget of 5, 10, or 15" ))
if studentprice<1:
    while studentprice <1:
        print("invalid price please try again!")
        studentprice = float(input())
elif studentprice>15:
    print ("you can have any object below")
    print(schoollist)
```

how do I make the program print the objects after it's done running? How can I make the program print the correct object based on the price of the user inputs?
the while loop is there so that when the user inputs a value less than 1 that means that they can't buy anything so the program will simply ask the user to reenter until the user types in a valid input.

Comment: Your 2 arrays have different length in your example. For a given price you want to have only one item or all the item that have a price below too ? Please provide an example input and the expected output (several examples can be a nice idea)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you give an example of something the user might type, and exactly what you want to show as a result?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding let me clarify. When the program starts it will ask the user to enter their "price" or the amount of money they are going to spend for the object. (in a way this lets the user know what they can purchase after they've inputted a budget or a "price") so lets say the program asks "enter price" and the user inputs 10, then since the list for the "price" of then corresponds to paper then the program should print "paper".

Comment: Also, I would like the program to print everything before the 10 "price" because the user can purchase both the paper and pen. (because pen is only worth 5 while the paper is worth 10)

Answer (score 0):

You're not too precise on what exactly you want to achieve but I hope that below lines will give you some food for thoughts while working down on your project:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

schoollist=["pen", "paper", "calculator"]
pricelist=[5, 12, 20]

# using dictionary of price - item as @SuppleSack suggested
pricetags = defaultdict(list)
for price, item in zip(pricelist, schoollist):
    pricetags[price].append(item)

userlist =[]
studentprice=int(input("enter your budget:" ))
# check for elements with prices in budget range
prices_in_budget = [price for price in pricetags.keys() if price <= studentprice]
# return items under the budget
print("With current budget you can have any of the following: ")
_ = [print(pricetags[price] + ' - ' + price) for price in prices_in_budget]
```

Output:
`enter your budget:15
With current budget you can have any of the following: 
['pen']
['paper']`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but it feels like you might find dictionaries as a helpful data structure for your (object : price) pairs, and then getting the correct object would be quite easy.